# How is this experiment going?

Tags: discussion

I am new to the site and have spent quite a bit of time reading and trying to learn the ropes and to post helpfully over the last few days. Activity seems very low right now. Maybe the widespread feeling that there are tons of low hanging fruit of ridiculous patents out there is incorrect. Or does understanding what is claimed and searching for it turn out to be harder than community members thought? I'd like to help.

Answer (score 8):

The slowdown experienced after a gala launch isn't all that unusual and certainly *not* unexpected. We launched this site outside our [normal process](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) of assuring we have critical mass of users *prior* to launch.

But this is a "special project" with a staff committed to building this project from the ground up. We are gathering up the expertise, and evaluating the features and support we'll need to make this project fly. There is a lot of work to do, but we've had some promising interest in our early trials.

This is a fully functional site ready for those who need it, and we really *do* appreciate the efforts and the hard-earned knowledge offered by users like you. Thank you, and keep up the good work! There is much more to come.